# ActiveMQ generating queues which don't exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jms, activemq-classic

I have a problem with using ActiveMQ in Spring application.

I have a few environments on separate machines. On each machine I had one ActiveMQ instance installed. Now, I realized that I can have only one ActiveMQ instance installed on one server, and few applications can use that ActiveMQ for sending messages. So, I must change queue names in order to have different queues for different environments (`"queue.search.sandbox"`, `"queue.search.production"`, ...).

After that change, now ActiveMQ is generating new queues, but also the old ones, although there is no such configuration for doing that.

I am using Java Spring application with Java configuration, not XML.

First, I create `queueTemplate` as a Spring bean:

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsAuditQueueTemplate() {
    log.debug("ActiveMQConfiguration jmsAuditQueueTemplate");
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    String queueName = "queue.audit.".concat(env.getProperty("activeMqBroker.queueName.suffix"));
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(new ActiveMQQueue(queueName));
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

Second, I create ActiveMQ `Listener` configuration:

```
@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsAuditQueueListenerContainer() {
    log.debug("ActiveMQConfiguration jmsAuditQueueListenerContainer");
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    dmlc.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    String queueName = "queue.audit.".concat(env.getProperty("activeMqBroker.queueName.suffix"));
    ActiveMQQueue activeMQ = new ActiveMQQueue(queueName);
    dmlc.setDestination(activeMQ);
    dmlc.setRecoveryInterval(30000);

    dmlc.setSessionTransacted(true);
    // To perform actual message processing
    dmlc.setMessageListener(auditQueueListenerService);

    dmlc.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
    // ... more parameters that you might want to inject ...
    return dmlc;
}
```

After building my application, as the result I have properly created queue with suffix (`"queue.audit.sandbox"`), but after some time ActiveMQ generates and the old version (`"queue.audit"`).

Does someone knows how ActiveMQ is doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any other piece of software that is subscribing to the Queue `queue.audit`?

Comment: No, there is not. Everything happens inside core application.

Comment: Delete the "data" directory, and use webconsole or jmx to check if there is connection to the old queues.

Comment: Btw you can have multiple activemq instance on the same server, you only have to change the listening port.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I know that I can have multiple ActiveMQ instances installed on the same server, but we wanted to avoid that. It is easier to track everything on this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably still an entry in the index for the queue, so when ActiveMQ restarts it is displaying the queue. If you want to be certain about destinations, use startup destinations and disable auto-creation by denying the "admin" permission to the connecting user account in the authorization entry

Comment: This sounds like a solution to my problem, but I haven't made any change in ActiveMQ configuration, and it just stopped creating queues. Like there is some parameter in configuration for recreation of unused queues after ActiveMQ restart...

Comment: The index is stored as part of kahadb, not the activemq configuration. Once the db-*.log files rotate out I imagine the queues won't show up. You could also make a backup of the kahadb folder, delete the .data file (index) and let ActiveMQ recreate the index.

Answer (score 0):

After some time ActiveMQ just stopped creating queues that don't exist. 
Now, we have expected behavior, without unnecessary queues.

Still I didn't found out what solved this problem, to be sincere...